# chilkat - How to use Chilkat.FileAccess.FileDelete function to delete all file using *.*

Tags: chilkat

I have the problem to use Chilkat.FileAccess.FileDelete to delete all file using *.*, the log says the following, how to handle the problem, thanks!

ChilkatLog:
  FileDelete:
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.75
    WindowsError: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    failedToDeleteFilepath: C:\TMP\untar001*.*
  --FileDelete
--ChilkatLog

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are passing wildcards to `FileAccess.FileDelete`, which doesn't accept wildcards. Unfortunately the Chilkat API doesn't provide means to enumerate files in a directory, so if you want to stick to the Chilkat API you would have to delete the entire directory:

```
fa.DirDelete("C:\\TMP");
```

Otherwise, using standard .NET:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
    "C:\\TMP", 
    "untar001*.*" , 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
    )
{
    fa.FileDelete(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chilkat to enumerate files in a directory, or enumerate files in an entire directory tree.

See the DirTree class here:  http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csDirTreeRef.html

and an example here: https://www.example-code.com/csharp/dirTree_iterate.asp